# How to: HTTP GET and POST request with parameters in Win 8 modern app using C# and XAML

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am using below code in C# .Net console app to make HTTP get and POST request  .And what to know how do we do this in Win 8 modern app using C# and XAML ?

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this [MSDN Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)